# 2012 Nissan Murano interior light won't go off

Tags: lights, electronics

2012 Nissan Murano interior light doesn't go off after door is closed. It does go off after 15 min. as it says in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

Which light ? The front dome light switches on by pushing it, it will click. If the door is open , the light is on so if it is pushed at that time nothing happens ( it is already on) . But when you close the door it stays on until the timer turns it off .  I have inadvertently done that and wondered why the light does not go off when the door is closed.

Comment: Thanks' it is the dome light and I have tried all 3 positions. It does turn off in the off position  and it stays on in the far right position but when youclose the door in the middle position it won't go until it times out in 15 minutes.

Comment: Mine is a 2011, in the middle position the light goes off in 10 seconds. But if you push the light lens , there is another switch that turns on the light.